# Android Manifest file- targetSDKVersion

Tags: android, android-manifest

If I set "targetSdkVersion=8", will application be able to run on Gingerbread devices and more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer it in short form: yes it will support every Version from `Android 2.2` (Froyo) to currently `Android 4.0.4` (ICS).
Here is an overview of the API Levels:

```
Android Version: API Level

Android 4.0.3:  15  
Android 4.0:    14 
Android 4.0.1:  14
Android 4.0.2:  14  
Android 3.2:    13  
Android 3.1.x : 12  
Android 3.0.x:  11  
Android 2.3.4:  10
Android 2.3.3:  10  
Android 2.3.2:  9
Android 2.3.1:  9
Android 2.3:    9   
Android 2.2.x:  8   
Android 2.1.x:  7   
Android 2.0.1:  6   
Android 2.0:    5   
Android 1.6:    4   
Android 1.5:    3   
Android 1.1:    2       
Android 1.0:    1
```

I hope I could help

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Answer (score 3):

It will run on devices from Froyo 2.2 and up... So, yes it will.